How to prove that $\sum_{n=-\infty,\\ n\neq-1,0,1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}|c_0|^2$ when $c_n$ are Fourier coefficients of a product
I need some help proving: $$\sum_{n=-\infty,\\ n\neq-1,0,1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}|c_0|^2$$
Given that $c_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of the products of two functions $a(s), b(s)$ of period $2\pi$ with normalized Fourier coefficients $a_n$, $b_n$:
$$a(s)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ins}, \qquad b(s)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{b_n}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ins}$$
$$\sum_n|a_n|^2=\sum_n|b_n|^2=1$$
$$\implies c_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_k a_k\cdot b_{n-k}$$
And given the condition that:
$$a_0=0, \qquad b_{-n}=b_n^*.$$
I know this must be true from numerical simulations. I've tried using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality on $|c_n|^2$ but couldn't prove the original inequality.

what is exactly the definition of $a_n, b_n$? not sure "normalized Fourier coefficients" is a standard definition - I guess you mean the $1/(2\pi)$ average of the usual but would rather know than guess

@Cristobal Mendez Add some detailed definition for $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$. I see some one has voted to close the question and I hate to see it closed.

I added the definitions of a(s), b(s). Hope that makes more clear the question

A counterexample: Take
$$a(s)=b(s)=1_{[0,\pi]}(s)-1_{(\pi, 2 \pi]}(s),$$
which implies that $a_0 = 0$ and $b_n = - b_{-n}^*$ since $b$ is real-valued. Then
$$c(s) = a(s)b(s) = 1,$$
so
$$c_0 = \sqrt{ 2 \pi},$$
yet
$$\sum_{n \neq 0} |c_n|^2 = 0$$
by orthogonality of $(e^{ins})$.
